# Azure DNS or the built in Office 365 DNS Service

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, dns-hosting

We're currently using a 3rd party DNS provider and the included Office 365 DNS Service. But we would like to consolidate this.

And since we are using Azure and Office 365 one of the two should be it.
Just not sure which one?

Any idea why Azure is better than Office 365 DNS?

Comment: which one supports DS, DANE or AAAA records...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are almost the same, but it's probably a better idea to migrate to Azure DNS. It's more flexible and the interface is just better. Currently, Office365 DNS management also got some limitations. A few ones that come to my mind:

- limit of 50 custom entries per domain
- does not allow you to change MX (to avoid breaking things)
- does not allow additional SPF records (because of built-in anti-spam)

There's not really much to say in terms of functionalities.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your DNS server supports TXT records and SRV records it really doesn't matter. You just need a DNS server to host the records needed for Office365. If you are already using Azure and you have DNS hosted via Azure then unless there is a good reason not to use it which you haven't shared then use Azure. It makes the most sense.

Please verify you create all of the required records. Information about the records is [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-DNS-records-for-Office-365-at-any-DNS-hosting-provider-7b7b075d-79f9-4e37-8a9e-fb60c1d95166?ui=en-US).